# Only password protect one file in folder with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I only want to password protect one file in a folder.  How can I do this with .htaccess?

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you want to password protect your `secret.html` file. Just create a `.htaccess` file in the same folder as the secret file, with the following content (you may need to customize some values according to your config:

```
<Files secret.html>
AuthName "Login"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /html/username/.htpasswd
require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
```

You can also use wildcards to filter some file types only. Imagine you want to password protect all zip files:

```
<FilesMatch "*.zip">
AuthName "Login"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /html/username/.htpasswd
require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Do you now how to do the opposite?  That is exclude one or two files from the password protect?

Comment: you need to have some criteria in order to use wildcards. For instance, imagine you want to password protect all .zip files: <FilesMatch "*.zip"> every other file will be unlocked.